# Can you sum or countif a drop down text list to a graph?

Tags: drop-down-menu, graph, sum, google-sheets, countif

So I made a spreadsheet that consists of dropdowns that have the text Fail, Completed and In Progress as the drop down fields. I'd like to know if there is a way I can take the data from the dropdowns and input that text data into a graph, so I can see what percentage/how much of the sheet has been completed?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, should be pretty simple. If your results are all in one column, let's say column B, then in column C you could have `=COUNTIF' formulas for each result:

```
          A         B           C
 Row 1  Test1      Fail      =COUNTIF(B:B,"Fail")
 Row 2  Test2    Completed   =COUNTIF(B:B,"Completed")
 Row 3  Test3      Fail      =COUNTIF(B:B,"In Progress")
 Row 4  Test4   In Progress
 Row 5  Test5      Fail
 Row 6  Test6    Completed
```

Then you would just highlight the 3 cells in the C column for your chart data, and go to Insert > Chart, and go from there.